# Suffix -smith in surnames

Tags: surnames

I recall reading once that the "smith" in some surnames stood for something like "the one who works with". For example: Coppersmith, the one who works with copper or deals with copper; Wordsmith has to with an individual that make a living by dealings with words (a poet?).

Is there any evidence on the validity of this "explanation"? When and how did surnames ending with "smith" originate?

Do you know of a good source (article, textbook, manuscript, papyrus) on the origin of some of the more common surnames in the English speaking world?

For instance, I believe that the suffix -son was intended to express the son of "name preceding *son*": for instance, Johnson (son of John), Nicholson (son of Nicholas?), etc.

Comment: Your questions seem interesting; however, I think that to get reasonably scoped answers, you should edit this post so that it is only about about *-smith* names. You can make a separate post for the question about *-son* names if needed.

Comment: I would go so far as to think that 'Smith' is the root, and the kinds of things worked on are the _prefixes_ (not 'smith' being the suffix). This is similar to 'Wright': Cartwright, Woodright, Wainwright,  (with or without the 'w') etc etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word "smith" once had a wider meaning. The Oxford English Dictionary has the following definition:

> A person who works skilfully with iron or other metals, making items by forging and hammering; esp. a blacksmith, a farrier. Also in figurative context. Formerly also occasionally: †a skilled worker in other arts or crafts (*obsolete*).

You can see this in action in a number of Old English texts. Joseph, husband of Mary is described as a smith, which according to the OED "translates [as] classical Latin *faber* [meaning] craftsman":

> *Nonne hic est fabri filius*: ahne ðis is smiðes *uel* wyrihta sunu?
>   <sub>[Matthew 13:55, *Lindisfarne Gospels*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gqk4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=%22wyrihta+sunu%22)</sub>

Similarly [*Beowulf*](https://books.google.com/books?id=iQZlDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=%22worhte+w%C3%A6pna+smi%C3%B0%22) talks about a "weapon smith":

> Swa hine fyrndagum worhte wæpna smið.

There's also this Late Old English quote:

> He is smið, & his heorð is seo gedrefodnysse
>   <sub>[Early English homilies](https://archive.org/stream/earlyenglishhomi00aelf#page/140/search/is+seo+gedrefodnysse)</sub>

(My translation: "He [the devil] is a smith and his furnace is the [tribulation](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED21705/track?counter=1&search_id=40620)".)

---

The word "smith" was also used as the second word in compounds.

In this example, "larsmiðas" means "teacher" or "counsellor", but its literal translation is something like "lore-smith":

> Þa se æðeling fand..þurh larsmiðas..on godes bocum hwær ahangen wæs..on rode treo rodora waldend.
>   <sub>[Elene](https://www.poetrynook.com/poem/elene)</sub>

Here's an example of "laughter-smith":

> Wæron hleahtorsmiðum handa belocene.
>   <sub>[Exodus](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/ascp/a01_02.htm)</sub>

This is translated by [one source](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11061-016-9504-6) as "laughter-makers":

> The hands of the (Egyptian scornful) laughter-makers were restrained (from plaudits).

Yet another relevant example from Old English is the following (with "wigsmiðas" meaning "idol-makers"):

> Þa wæron deofulgild deorce hæþenra golde and seolfre, þa her geara menn worhtan wigsmiðas wræste mid folmum.
>   <sub>[The Paris Psalter](http://www.bede.net/misc/runes.html)</sub>

This [translates](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11061-016-9504-6) as:

> Then there were faithless devilish idols of the heathen, gold and silver, which here long ago people, idol-makers, made long-lasting with (their) hands.

---

See also: [Wonder-Smiths and Others: *smið* Compounds in Old English Poetry—With an Excursus on *hleahtor*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11061-016-9504-6) (already linked above but worth another mention.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that explanation is correct—for most of them.

Examples of scholarly referencess on the subject include 1. [*A Dictionary of English Surnames*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Uv1M6Au9yVYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22A+Dictionary+of+English+Surnames%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4qKmCqsLdAhXhYN8KHZMGC7QQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) and 2. [*The Oxford Dictionary of Family Names in Britain and Ireland*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0AyDDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

As the OP suggests, most last names that end in *-smith* are 'occupational last names', where the *smith* typically means, roughly, 'maker of'. But there are some exceptions: ***Goodesmith/Goodsmith, Hudsmith***, and ***Athersmith***. ***Silversmith*** is a different kind of exception; see below.

In ***Goodesmith/Goodsmith*** and ***Hudsmith***, the root is not really *smith*, but rather

> ME *maugh, mough* which may be from ON *mágr* ‘brother-, father- or son-in-law’, OE *māga* ‘relative, son’, OE *māge* ‘female relative’, or OE *magu* ‘child, son, servant’.

See e.g. the entry for *Hudsmith* [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=0AyDDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1349&dq=Hudsmith%20%22Hudd%E2%80%99s%22&pg=PA1349#v=onepage&q=Hudsmith%20%22Hudd%E2%80%99s%22&f=false).

In ***Athersmith***, the *-smith* comes from one of two sources. First, it may denote 'someone who lived, and presumably worked, at a smithy (Old English *smiþþe*)'. The second possibility is that it comes from OE *smēðe* ('free from roughness, not harsh, polished; soft; suave; agreeable'; see [here](https://www.etymonline.com/word/smooth#etymonline_v_23743)), in which case it is

> a locative name possibly also from Middle English *at ther smethe* ‘dweller at the smooth, level place’'

See [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=0AyDDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1349&dq=Hudsmith%20%22Hudd%E2%80%99s%22&pg=PA92#v=onepage&q=Athersmith&f=false).

In either case, unlike most other *-smith*s, *Athersmith* does not come from 'a maker of something', but it rather has to do with where the person lived.

***Silversmith***

At the end of the day, this is an 'occupational' surname just like *Goldsmith* and other *-smith* occupational surnames I list below. However, the historical origin of *Silversmith* is very different from that of these other surnames.

Shockingly enough, unlike the surnames listed below, *Silversmith* seems to **not** have been used as a surname in pre-modern British isles. Instead, it seems to come from America, as a  'part-translation of German and Ashkenazic Jewish *Silberstein*'. I base this claim on [this entry](https://books.google.com/books?id=FJoDDAAAQBAJ&lpg=RA2-PA351&dq=surname%20Silversmith&pg=PR8#v=onepage&q=Silversmith&f=false) from *Dictionary of American Family Names*, and on the fact that neither the two scholarly references above nor the 1860 *Patronymica Britannica, a dictionary of the family names of the United Kingdom* have an entry for *Silversmith* (see [here](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=00cBAAAAQAAJ&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA315)). This despite the fact that all three of these references do have *Goldsmith*, which is indeed an occupational surname with a long history of presence in England, just as you'd expect.

**A list of *-smith* surnames in *A Dictionary of English Surnames***

Here are all *-smith*s that have entries in *A Dictionary of English Surnames*. The abbreviation 'OE' means 'Old English'; 'ME', 'Middle English'; and 'ON', 'Old Norse'.

> **Arrowsmith, Arsmith, Harrismith,
>   Harrowsmith**
>
> : Roger *le Aruesmuth* 1278 AssSt; William *le Arwesmyth* 1324 FFEss; Richard *Arsmith* Eliz Bardsley. OE *arwe* ‘arrow’ and *smith*. A smith who makes arrows, especially iron
>   arrow-heads (1278 MED). *Harrismith* and *Harrowsmith* are rare but exist side by side with *Arrowsmith* in Yorks and Lancs.
>
> **Athersmith**
>
> : John atter *Smythe* (1330 PN D 386) lived at the smithy (OE *smiþþe*) and was
>   presumably a blacksmith. The surname might also derive from ME *at ther smethe* ‘dweller at the smooth, level place’ (OE *smēðe*). cf. William *del Smethe* 1327 SRSf.
>
> **Brownsmith**
>
> : Thomas *le Brounesmyth* 1296 Wak (Y); William *Brounsmyth* 1327 SRSo. OE *brūn* and *smið* ‘brown smith’, ‘a worker in copper and brass’.
>
> **Coppersmith**
>
> : Richard *Copersmid* 1212–23 Bart (Lo); Robert *copersmith* eHy 3 ib.; John *le copersmyth* 1305 LoCt. ‘Maker of copper utensils’ (1327 MED). cf. Hugo *Coperman* 1202 P (We), Stephen *le Coperbeter* 1286 LLB A.
>
> **Goldsmith, Gouldsmith**
>
> : Roger *Goldsmiz* 1250 MESO (Nf); Thomas *Goldsmith* 1255 Ass (Ess); John *le
>   Goldesmethe* 1309 LLB D. OE *goldsmið* ‘goldsmith’.
>
> **Goodesmith, Goodsmith**
>
> : John *Godesmaghe* 1351 FrY; Margaret *Goodsmyth* 1525 SRSx. ‘Relative of *Gode*’, cf. HUDSMITH.
>
> **Greensmith**
>
> : Thomas *Grenesmyth* 1523 RochW. ‘Coppersmith.’
>
> **Harrismith**
>
> : v. ARROWSMITH
>
> **Harrowsmith**
>
> : v. ARROWSMITH
>
> **Hudsmith**
>
> : Thomas *Huddemogh* 1332 SRLa; William *Hudmagh* 1379 PTY; Thomas *Huddesmawth* 1464 FeuDu; Cuthbert *Hodgemaght, Hodgemaughthe* 1545–6 NorwW (Nf); Ralph *Hudsmyth* 1582 PrGR. ‘Hudd’s brother-in-law.’ cf. Richard *Gepmouthe* and v. WATMOUGH.
>
> **Locksmith**
>
> : Walter, Roger *le Loksmyth’* 1255 Ass (Ess), 1293 Pinchbeck (Sf); John *Loc Smyth* 1279 AssNb; Robert *Locsmyth* 1279 RH (Hu). OE *loc* ‘lock’ and *smið*, ‘locksmith’. cf. William *Locwricht* 13th AD iv (Lo).
>
> **Naesmith**
>
> : v. NAYSMITH
>
> **Naismith**
>
> : v. NAYSMITH
>
> **Naysmith, Naismith, Naesmith, Nasmyth**
>
> : Roger *Knifsmith* 1246–89 Bart (Lo); Adam *Knyfsmith* 1285 AssLa; Saman *le Knyfsmyth* 1310 LLB D; William *Knysmyt* 1326 AssSt; Robert *Knysmithe* 1594 Bardsley; John *Naysmith* n.d. ib. OE *cnīf* ‘knife’ and *smið* ‘smith’, a cutler.
>
> **Platsmith**
>
> : John *Platesmyth* 1379 PTY. ‘A maker of plate armour’, ME *plate*, OE *smiþ*.
>
> **Sersmith**
>
> : v. SHEARSMITH
>
> **Shearsmith, Sersmith**
>
> : Walter *Scheresmythe* 1325 ParlWrits (Gl); Geoffrey *Sheresmyth* 1391 FrY. ‘A maker of shears, scissors’, OE *scēarra* and *smið*.
>
> **Shoesmith, Shoosmith**
>
> : William *Le Shosmith*, *Sosmyth* 1288 MESO, 1296 SRSx. OE *scōh*, *smið* ‘shoeingsmith’, maker of horseshoes.
>
> **Shucksmith**
>
> : v. SUCKSMITH
>
> **Smith, Smithe, Smyth, Smythe, Smye**
>
> : (i) Ecceard *Smið* c975 OEByn (Du); Ælfword *þe Smith* c1100 ib. (So); William *le Smyth* 1275 AssSo; Julian’ *le Smithes* 1279 RH (O); John *Smye* 1524 SRSf. OE *smið* ‘smith, blacksmith, farrier’. Early examples are common in the Latin form FABER. (ii) William *atte Smithe*, Thomas *de la Smythe* 1313 AD i (Sx); Robert *atte Smyth* 1332 SRSx. ‘Worker at the smithy’, OE *smiþþe*.
>
> **Sucksmith, Shucksmith**
>
> : ‘A maker of plough-shares’, OFr *soc*, OE *smiþ*.
>
> **Weldsmith**
>
> : v. WILDSMITH
>
> **Whilesmith**
>
> : v. WILDSMITH
>
> **Whitesmith**
>
> : Richard, William *le Wytesmith* 1260 Cl (O), 1279 RH (C); John *le Wytesmyt, le Whitesmyth* 1313, 1332 SRWa. OE *hwīt* and *smið* ‘white-smith’, a tin-smith (1302 NED).
>
> **Wildsmith, Wilesmith, Weldsmith, Whilesmith**
>
> : Euota *Welsmyth’* 1319 SR (Ess); Ivo *le Welsmyth* 1327 SR (Ess); Anne *Wilesmith* 1787 Bardsley. This surname has been variously explained as a corruption of *weld-smith*, a forger in iron, weald-smith, and the smith in the wild, none of which is satisfactory, nor is Bardsley’s association of the name with wool. *Welsmyth* is from OE **hwēol-smið* ‘wheelsmith’, a maker of wheels, especially the iron parts. cf. WHEELWRIGHT. The vowel was raised to [i] (*Wheelsmith*), then shortened to *Willsmith*, which, with an intrusive *d*, became *Wildsmith*. ME *W(h)īlsmith* developed normally to *W(h)ilesmith*. cf. *Whygler* for *Wheeler*, *Whilwright* for *Wheelwright*, and the development of *weald* to *wild*.

There is no entry for ***Wordsmith*** in any of the four dictionaries mentioned above. However, I only have access to the *American* one through google books, and so it is possible that it has an entry for it after all, but that we just can't see it.

On the related topic of surnames that *begin* with *Smith-* (other than *Smith,* which I already included above):

> **Smitham**
>
> : Robert *de Smetham* 1275 RH (D); Thomas *Smitham* 1642 PrD. From *Smytham* in Little Torrington (D).
>
> **Smither, Smithers**
>
> : John *Smythiere* 1379 AssWa. ‘Smith, hammerman.’ cf. ‘The Jorneymen…of all oþer Craftes…except hakmen and smythers wurche in hur own houses and nott in hur masters housz’ (1435 NED).
>
> **Smitherman, Smythyman**
>
> : Robert *Smythyman* 1309 Cl (Y). ‘Smithy man’, worker at the smithy.
>
> **Smithies, Smithyes, Smythyes**
>
> : John *del Smythy* 1332 SRLa, 1385 ShefA; John *Smythes*, *Smythies* 1568,1586 FrY; Thomas *Smiddies* 1629 ib. ‘Worker at the smithy’, ME *smythy*.
>
> **Smithson, Smythson, Smisson**
>
> : Reginald *le Smythessone* 1296 SRSx; Henry *le Smithson* 1324 Wak (Y); Peter *Smitson* 1327 SRY. ‘Son of the smith.’
>
> **Smithwhite, Smorthwaite, Smorflt, Smurtbwaite, Smurfit, Smallthwaite**
>
> : Henry *de Smetwayt* 1285 AssLa; Thomas *de Smythuait* 1327 SRY; Matilda *Smarthwate* 1489 GildY; Robert *Smerwhaitt* 1518 ib.; Thomas *Smirthwaite* 1577 FrY; Thomas *Smorthwait* 1627 ib.; Matthew *Smurwhaite* 1657 ib.; Edward *Smurfett* son of Matthew *Smurfett* 1713 ib. In Cumberland there is a Smaithwaite in Keswick and another in Lamplugh, *Smathwaitis* c1280, *Smerthwayte* 1530, *Smethwayte* 1552 (PN Cu 314, 407), whilst in Guiseley (Y) we have *Smerthwayt* 1323 Calv, ‘small clearing’ (ON *smár*). In Cumberland, too, we find two *Smallthwaites*, neither recorded before 1611, which may be identical in origin, with late substitution of English *small* for Scandinavian *smár*. The first two examples above may contain OE *smēðe* ‘smooth’.
>
> **Smithwick**
>
> : Adam *de Smithewyk* 1327 SRSx; Roger *de Smythewyk* 1332 SRSx. From *Smethwick* (Ches), or from a lost *Smithwick* in Southover (Sussex), last recorded c1608 (PN Sx 323).
>
> **Smithyman**
>
> : v. SMITHERMAN

On the general topic of how these things are determined, read the introduction (and the prefaces) of the *Dictionary*. Here is the very beginning of the introduction:

> The purpose of a Dictionary of Surnames is to explain the meaning of names, not to treat of genealogy and family history. The fact that Robert le Turnur lived in Staffordshire in 1199 and that there was a William de Kouintre in London in 1230 does not mean that they were the ancestors of all or any of the modern Turners or Coventrys. To establish this, a fully documented pedigree would be required and very few families can carry back their history so far. Throughout the Middle Ages surnames were constantly changing. William Tyndale was known as Huchyns when living in Gloucestershire. Oliver Cromwell was a Williams and David Livingstone was a McLeay. Even today families change their names. Blackden has become Blacktin, Hogg has been changed to Hodd and Livemore has superseded Livermore—all within living memory.
>
> The modern form of many of our surnames is comparatively recent, often preserving a phonetic spelling found in a seventeenth- or eighteenth-century parish register. When some of the Sussex Bourers migrated to Kent in the seventeenth century they adopted the form Bowra. *Pharaoh* is a reconstructed spelling of *Faro*, originally *Farrer*, found also as *Farrey, Farrah* and *Farrow* in the seventeenth century. The Suffolk Deadman is a corruption of Debenham and Tudman of Tuddenham. Each surname has its pedigree which must be traced before the meaning can be discovered, and even then the true origin cannot be decided unless the family pedigree can be carried back far enough to fix definitely the original medieval form. A modern White may owe his name to an ancestor bearing the Anglo-Saxon name of *Hwīta*, or to one nicknamed ‘the fair’, or to an original home in the bend of a river. The original Howard may have been a ewe-herd or a hayward, or he may have borne either the French name *Huard* or the Old German name *Howard*. The modern forms often conceal rather than reveal information.
>
> The English language lacks terms corresponding to the French *sobriquet* and *nom de famille*. Today, surname means an inherited family name; originally it meant simply an additional name and it is used in this sense in this book. Only very occasionally can early medieval surnames be proved to be hereditary, and any attempt to distinguish them would end in inaccuracy and confusion.

Comment: I have a feeling that your reference is not very comprehensive. It doesn't seem to contain 'Silversmith' which is a common English surname.

Comment: On second thought, the limitations are probably Google books'

Comment: Anyway, whether a few very common items are left out, the list you have supports the, what I would call, obvious, that they are all smiths of some kind.

Comment: @Mitch No, the full version lacks *Silversmith* also.

Comment: @Mitch Interestingly, in the entry for ***Silver***, it reads, ": (i) Lucas, John *Siluer* 1205–13 Seals (L), 1301 SRY. OE *silfor* ‘silver’, metonymic for a silversmith. cf. Robert *Silverhewer* 1212 Cur (Y), William *Sylvereour* 1417 FrY. (ii) Thomas *atte Selure* 1327 SRWo; Thomas *of the silvere* 1332 ib. ‘Dweller by the silvery stream’, OE * *seolfre,* * *sylfre,* as at Silver Beck (Cumb) or Silver (Devon). v. MELS.

Comment: @Mitch I don't know why *Silversmith* is not included. It's a good question. Nevertheless, what *is* included seems to be supported by solid historical and linguistic analysis. Perhaps, contrary to what one might expect, *Silversmith* turns out to be surprisingly difficult to definitively trace all the way back to the Middle Ages? I do not know.

Comment: @Mitch [*The Oxford Dictionary of Family Names in Britain and Ireland*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0AyDDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) doesn't have *Silversmith*, either.

Comment: @Mitch On the other hand, both dictionaries include ***Goldsmith***, which is indeed an occupational surname, just as you'd expect. Very strange!

Comment: @Mitch *Patronymica Britannica, a dictionary of the family names of the United Kingdom* (1860) doesn't have *Silversmith* (see [here](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=00cBAAAAQAAJ&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA315)), but it does have *Goldsmith* (see [here](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=00cBAAAAQAAJ&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA132)). On the other hand, *Dictionary of American Family Names* [does](https://books.google.com/books?id=FJoDDAAAQBAJ&lpg=RA2-PA351&dq=surname%20Silversmith&pg=PR8#v=onepage&q=Silversmith&f=false), but it says it is 'part-translation of German and Ashkenazic Jewish *Silberstein*'.

Comment: @Mitch Surprisingly, it is beginning to look as if *Silversmith* simply **was not** used as a surname in pre-modern England!

Comment: Re: pre-modern England - whatever the time period in which it became common, X-smith is still a smith of X.

Comment: Like -er is the (actual suffix) version for makers, Fletcher (arrows), Sawyer (for lumber), Cooper (for barrels) etc

Comment: Which is all to say, great research! 9just for one supposed false false-negative

Comment: @Mitch Thanks! Yes, this is pretty much what I'm saying in the current version of my answer.